# Google map did not draw properly whenever number of lat & lang point is huge

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have `array of lat and long`. The `length of array can be 200 to 2000` and `want to draw route through these points in google map`.

**I am using the following code but it did not give proper result.**

### Issue:

**Its drawing a discontinue/irregular line sometimes ,whenever no of lat & long records is huge.**

```
      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
var MapPoints =[
      {
        "title": 'Agents current location',
        "lat": '18.648661666666666',
        "lng": '73.78641833333333',
        "address": 'Agents current location',
        "type": 'current'
    },

     {
        "title": 'Checkin',
        "lat": '18.639178333333334',
        "lng": '73.79405',
        "address": 'Checkin',
        "type": 'checkin'
    }
        ];
var routecoordinates = [[{"lat":"18.639178333333334","lng":"73.79405"},{"lat":"18.639215","lng":"73.794065"},{"lat":"18.639151666666667","lng":"73.79418333333334"},{"lat":"18.639136666666666","lng":"73.79418833333334"},{"lat":"18.639136666666666","lng":"73.79418833333334"},{"lat":"18.639136666666666","lng":"73.79418833333334"},{"lat":"18.639171666666666","lng":"73.79413"}],[{"lat":"18.639171666666666","lng":"73.79413"},{"lat":"18.639171666666666","lng":"73.79413"},{"lat":"18.639171666666666","lng":"73.79413"},{"lat":"18.6632","lng":"73.78678666666666"},{"lat":"18.663186666666665","lng":"73.78671333333334"},{"lat":"18.663133333333334","lng":"73.78676833333334"},{"lat":"18.663081666666667","lng":"73.78682333333333"},{"lat":"18.66307","lng":"73.78683333333333"}],[{"lat":"18.66307","lng":"73.78683333333333"},{"lat":"18.662995000000002","lng":"73.78700333333333"},{"lat":"18.662995000000002","lng":"73.78702"},{"lat":"18.662998333333334","lng":"73.78703666666667"},{"lat":"18.662946666666667","lng":"73.78711833333334"},{"lat":"18.662903333333336","lng":"73.78721333333333"},{"lat":"18.662838333333333","lng":"73.78732166666667"},{"lat":"18.662746666666667","lng":"73.78733666666668"}],[{"lat":"18.662746666666667","lng":"73.78733666666668"},{"lat":"18.662836666666667","lng":"73.7872"},{"lat":"18.662883333333333","lng":"73.78726499999999"},{"lat":"18.662958333333332","lng":"73.78737333333333"},{"lat":"18.662985","lng":"73.78744499999999"},{"lat":"18.662881666666667","lng":"73.78753499999999"},{"lat":"18.66291","lng":"73.78758666666666"},{"lat":"18.663085000000002","lng":"73.787595"}],[{"lat":"18.663085000000002","lng":"73.787595"},{"lat":"18.66283","lng":"73.78750833333334"},{"lat":"18.662786666666666","lng":"73.78742666666668"},{"lat":"18.662786666666666","lng":"73.78742666666668"},{"lat":"18.6628","lng":"73.78753666666667"},{"lat":"18.662793333333333","lng":"73.78753666666667"},{"lat":"18.662786666666666","lng":"73.78741833333333"},{"lat":"18.662778333333332","lng":"73.78736666666667"}],[{"lat":"18.662778333333332","lng":"73.78736666666667"},{"lat":"18.66287","lng":"73.78718"},{"lat":"18.66292","lng":"73.7871"},{"lat":"18.66293","lng":"73.78700666666667"},{"lat":"18.662965","lng":"73.78692666666667"},{"lat":"18.66301","lng":"73.78685666666667"},{"lat":"18.66305","lng":"73.786765"},{"lat":"18.663063333333334","lng":"73.78671666666668"}],[{"lat":"18.663063333333334","lng":"73.78671666666668"},{"lat":"18.66276","lng":"73.78662333333334"},{"lat":"18.663498333333333","lng":"73.78647166666666"},{"lat":"18.66257166666667","lng":"73.78524999999999"},{"lat":"18.66238333333333","lng":"73.784495"},{"lat":"18.661785000000002","lng":"73.78371999999999"},{"lat":"18.661973333333332","lng":"73.78262500000001"},{"lat":"18.664985","lng":"73.78464833333334"}],[{"lat":"18.664985","lng":"73.78464833333334"},{"lat":"18.659266666666667","lng":"73.77801833333334"},{"lat":"18.658726666666666","lng":"73.77779000000001"},{"lat":"18.657511666666668","lng":"73.77928"},{"lat":"18.657111666666665","lng":"73.77970666666667"},{"lat":"18.657291666666666","lng":"73.77968833333333"},{"lat":"18.657286666666668","lng":"73.77968000000001"},{"lat":"18.65722","lng":"73.77964666666666"}],[{"lat":"18.65722","lng":"73.77964666666666"},{"lat":"18.65722","lng":"73.77964666666666"},{"lat":"18.657136666666666","lng":"73.77970499999999"},{"lat":"18.657136666666666","lng":"73.77970499999999"},{"lat":"18.657136666666666","lng":"73.77970499999999"},{"lat":"18.657136666666666","lng":"73.77970499999999"},{"lat":"18.65705","lng":"73.77973333333333"},{"lat":"18.657045","lng":"73.77973666666666"}],[{"lat":"18.657045","lng":"73.77973666666666"},{"lat":"18.657045","lng":"73.77973666666666"},{"lat":"18.657045","lng":"73.77973666666666"},{"lat":"18.657018333333333","lng":"73.77974666666667"},{"lat":"18.657018333333333","lng":"73.77974833333333"},{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"},{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"},{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"}],[{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"},{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"},{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"},{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"},{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"},{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"},{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"},{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"}],[{"lat":"18.657011666666666","lng":"73.77974666666667"},{"lat":"18.65707666666667","lng":"73.779675"},{"lat":"18.65707666666667","lng":"73.779675"},{"lat":"18.65707666666667","lng":"73.779675"},{"lat":"18.657055","lng":"73.77967666666667"},{"lat":"18.657055","lng":"73.77967666666667"},{"lat":"18.657055","lng":"73.77967666666667"},{"lat":"18.657055","lng":"73.77967666666667"}],[{"lat":"18.657055","lng":"73.77967666666667"},{"lat":"18.657055","lng":"73.77967666666667"},{"lat":"18.657055","lng":"73.77967666666667"},{"lat":"18.657055","lng":"73.77967666666667"},{"lat":"18.657055","lng":"73.77967666666667"},{"lat":"18.657055","lng":"73.77967666666667"},{"lat":"18.646343333333334","lng":"73.78805833333332"},{"lat":"18.646421666666665","lng":"73.78802333333333"}],[{"lat":"18.646421666666665","lng":"73.78802333333333"},{"lat":"18.64644333333333","lng":"73.78812500000001"},{"lat":"18.64644333333333","lng":"73.78812500000001"},{"lat":"18.646335","lng":"73.78815333333334"},{"lat":"18.646441666666664","lng":"73.78812500000001"},{"lat":"18.64644333333333","lng":"73.78812500000001"},{"lat":"18.64644333333333","lng":"73.78812666666666"},{"lat":"18.649493333333332","lng":"73.78677333333333"}],[{"lat":"18.649493333333332","lng":"73.78677333333333"},{"lat":"18.648661666666666","lng":"73.78641833333333"}]];
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel: false
    });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < MapPoints.length; i++) {
         var data = MapPoints[i]
         var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
         var icon = "";
         switch (data.type) {
            case "checkin":
                icon = "blue";
                break;
            case "pending":
                icon = "red";
                break;
            case "intransit":
                icon = "yellow";
                break;
            case "complete":
                icon = "green";
                break;
            case "cancel":
                icon = "purple";
                break;
            case "current":
                icon = "current";
                break;
        }
        if(icon=="current"){
            icon = "http://example.com/images/ins.png";
        }
        else
        {
         icon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/" + icon + ".png";
        }
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon)
            });
            //flightPlanCoordinates.push(marker.getPosition());
            bounds.extend(marker.position);

            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infowindow.setContent(data.address);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);

    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var k = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var flightPlanCoordinates = []; 
        var coordinates = routecoordinates[k];  
        for (j = 0; j < coordinates.length; j++) {
             var data = coordinates[j]
             var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
             flightPlanCoordinates.push(myLatlng);
        }
        var start = flightPlanCoordinates[0];
        var end = flightPlanCoordinates[flightPlanCoordinates.length - 1];
        var waypts = [];
        for (var j = 1; j < flightPlanCoordinates.length - 1; j++) {
          waypts.push({
            location: flightPlanCoordinates[j],
            stopover: true,
          });
        }
        var request = {
                        origin: start,
                        destination: end,
                        waypoints: waypts,
                        optimizeWaypoints: true,
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                      };
          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            //alert(k);   
            //document.getElementById('status').innerHTML +="request status:"+status+k+"<br>"; 
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                  var polylineOptionsActual = {
                  strokeColor  : '#FF0000',
                  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                  strokeWeight : 5};

                     var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
                     directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
                     directionsRenderer.setOptions( { polylineOptions: polylineOptionsActual, suppressMarkers: true} );
                     directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
            }
            else{}
          });
         k++;
         if (k == routecoordinates.length) {
          clearInterval(interval);
           }

         }, 600);
  }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>


<div  id="opacity-bg" class="opacity-bg">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean with ` but it did not give proper result` ? show  nothings? , error?

Comment: You need to add error checking `if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { // good route } else{ //error }`. You are probably getting a status response of `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`

Comment: So what status *are* you getting? If you posted a runnable link then it would be possible to debug and diagnose what's going on.

Comment: Why down vote.. Cannot understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I worked with die google-maps API some years ago, I found about this clever function google uses, to prevent DOS attacks.
If you question more than five locations, the answering time will slow down to demotivate bots.
I build a workaround by requesting in a loop, waiting several miliseconds inbetween.

Might this be your issue? Try it with an Array of length 5, then 6 or 10.